# Validate JsonPatchDocument request operations before applying it in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json-patch

I need to validate the JsonPatchDocument which is coming in the request before applying it to my object.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUserByIdAsync([Required][StringLength(40)] string id, [Required][FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<UserPatch> patchDocument)
```

I only need to validate the operations part like -
If there is an operation for replace, and the path/value variable is null/empty then it should return 400 bad request. Similarly for other operations like move, copy, add etc.

I am currently using the switch case as below :

```
    foreach (var operation in patchDocument.Operations)
    {
        var op = operation.op;
        var path = operation.path;
        var value = operation.value;
        var from = operation.from;
        switch (op)
        {
            case "add":
            case "replace":
            case "test":
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) || value == null)
                {
                    return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
                }
                break;
            case "copy":
            case "move":
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(from))
                {
                    return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
                }
                break;
            case "remove":
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                {
                    return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
                }
                break;
            default:
                return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        }
    }
```

But in the pipeline I have codeclimate configured which breaks the pipeline if any method is having cognitive complexity more than 20, I thought changing to if-else would solve the problem but the complexity is still at 28.

[Cognitive Complexity](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/cognitive-complexity)

I need some approach which can validate the request and the complexity reduces.

Edit:
I updated the method as below

```
private static bool ValidatePatchRequest(JsonPatchDocument<UserPatch> patchDocument)
{
    var validationResult = false;

    foreach (var item in patchDocument.Operations)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.op))
        {
            validationResult = false;
            break;
        }

        if (item.op == "add" || item.op == "test" || item.op == "replace")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.path) || item.value == null)
            {
                validationResult = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (item.op == "copy" || item.op == "move")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.path) || item.from == null)
            {
                validationResult = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (item.op == "remove")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.path))
            {
                validationResult = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        validationResult = true;
    }

    return validationResult;
}
```

Below is the error I am getting during build pipeline execution.

> [{"engine_name":"structure","fingerprint":"7558ff4c7ee81fda7b1f****","categories":["Complexity"],"check_name":"method_complexity","content":{"body":"#
> Cognitive Complexity\nCognitive Complexity is a measure of how
> difficult a unit of code is to intuitively understand. Unlike
> Cyclomatic Complexity, which determines how difficult your code will
> be to test, Cognitive Complexity tells you how difficult your code
> will be to read and comprehend.\n\n### A method's cognitive complexity
> is based on a few simple rules:\n* Code is not considered more complex
> when it uses shorthand that the language provides for collapsing
> multiple statements into one\n* Code is considered more complex for
> each "break in the linear flow of the code"\n* Code is considered
> more complex when "flow breaking structures are nested"\n\n###
> Further reading\n* [Cognitive Complexity
> docs](https://docs.codeclimate.com/v1.0/docs/cognitive-complexity)\n*
> [Cognitive Complexity: A new way of measuring
> understandability](https://www.sonarsource.com/docs/CognitiveComplexity.pdf)\n"},"description":"Method
> `ValidatePatchRequest` has a Cognitive Complexity of 28 (exceeds 20
> allowed). Consider
> refactoring.","location":{"path":"****Controller.cs","lines":{"begin":233,"end":276}},"other_locations":[],"remediation_points":950000,"severity":"minor","type":"issue"},
> {"name":"csharp.parse.succeeded","type":"measurement","value":15,"engine_name":"structure"},
> {"name":"csharp.parse.succeeded","type":"measurement","value":15,"engine_name":"duplication"}]

Comment: Move validation into separate method.

Comment: Initially I had validation in controller, but currently it is in separate method and still the same problem.

Comment: Can you please add the error from the build tool? And actual method which it complains about?

Comment: "description":"Method `ValidatePatchRequest` has a Cognitive Complexity of 28 (exceeds 20 allowed). Consider refactoring.","location":{"path":"****Controller.cs","lines":{"begin":233,"end":276}},"other_locations":[],"remediation_points":950000,"severity":"minor","type":"issue"},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes across the same issue, this is how I resolved it.
I changed the method as below and it reduced the cognitive complexity less than 20 and the pipeline was successful.

```
private static bool ValidatePatchRequest(JsonPatchDocument<UserPatch> patchDocument)
{
    var validationResult = false;
    foreach (var item in patchDocument.Operations)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.op))
        {
            validationResult = false;
            break;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.path))
        {
            validationResult = false;
            break;
        }

        if ((item.op == "add" || item.op == "test" || item.op == "replace") && item.value == null)
        {
            validationResult = false;
            break;
        }

        if ((item.op == "copy" || item.op == "move") && item.from == null)
        {
            validationResult = false;
            break;
        }

        validationResult = true;
    }

    return validationResult;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).